# Troubleshooting DateTimeConvertor rejected output

Tags: fme-transformer

I have an Excel dataset. I am translating two time attributes named "Occurred_time" and "Reported_time" with this format:%I:%M:%S%p to this format:%H:%M:%S.

Although it shows me the Preview Data, the result is rejected. I can't find what is the problem.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What version of FME are you using?